# error to import MySQLdb in python

Tags: python, mysql

I have error to connect existing mysql database in python and i unable to do

`pip install mysql command`

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host='10.10', port=3306, user='system', passwd='xyz' db='Reporting')
print(db)
```

I want to retrieve the data from mysql database in python.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip install MySQL-python` instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the dependencies before installation with `pip`.

```
apt-get install python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

And than, the installation with `pip` like the answer of Zart should work.

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

***The above answer is only for Linux System.***

For Windows you can download the `.whl` file from here [mysqlclient](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient) and install it. Please download the right version. `win32` for 32 bit. `amd64` for 64 bit. `cp27` for python 2.7, `cp34` for python 3.4, `cp35` for python 3.5

Comment: and when i excecute pip install MySQL-python its said its block by systemsdministrator

Comment: ok, you must run the command under root. `sudo apt-get ...` and `sudo pip...`

Comment: Thanks for reply but this one is also not work. its said "sudo" is false or could not be found

Comment: Ok, sorry. My answer was for Linux system. You can try again with my new answer.

Comment: Sorry. I can't check it. I don't have a windows PC

Comment: okay no problem.Thank you for help. I have mysql workbench so why we need this file.